# Bengali font not showing correctly in One Note for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, fonts, microsoft-onenote

Today, for the first time I was trying OneNote for Windows 10. While I was taking notes in English, it was working perfectly. But when I tried to type in Bengali, it became terrible.

[image: error]

As you can see in this image, the fonts in the left panel are being displayed correctly. Also, if I copy-paste in the 'note body', then also it works fine. But when I type something in the title or body, then they are distorted. This issue was raised in the [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onenote-bengali-language-problem/85c385c1-7438-4ac1-bfee-64f26d31e1e6?page=1) more than 1 year ago. The solution provided by a 'Microsoft Agent' was:

> Hi All,
>
> We researched a lot about this issue, and we found that the problem has nothing to do with the OneNote application, but with the keyboard.
>
> If you want to type the correct letters, we recommend that you could use Avro keyboard instead of others.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Jazlyn

Now, I am using Avro and the problem still persists. One of the users suggested using the Nirmala UI font. I also tried that but still no solution (in fact the font in the note body of the image shown is Nirmala UI). The font used in the title of the image is 'Shonar Bangla'. I tried using 'Solamani Lipi', 'Kalpurush', and 'Siyam Rupali' fonts. None solved the problem.

Is there any solution to this problem?

OS: Windows 10 (updated), Keyboard: Avro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution in [a blog](https://ednoub.blogspot.com/2021/09/onenote-bengali-language-problem.html?showComment=1633971073381#c3217514611016446944). I am adding the solution here as it is encouraged not to simply share a link of a solution as the link can be obsolete in the future.

To solve the problem stated in the question, one needs to set the OneNote language to Bangla. This can be done by right-clicking on the note and then selecting the 'Bangla(Bangladesh)' or 'Bengali(India)' option in 'Set Language'. If one has already typed some text, then he/she needs to first select all text and then change the language. Also, you need to change the language separately for the 'Title' and the 'Body' of the note.

[image: solution]

The corrected output of the image in the question:
[image]

The solution was so simple that I was astonished! I am wondering why the Microsoft staff couldn't provide this simple solution although they claimed that they had 'researched' 'a lot' about this issue.

Addendum (02 March, 2024):

On **Onenote** (*not the one named "Onenote for Windows 10"*), you need to do it from the "Review" tab. There you will find the "Set Proofing Language Option" under the "Language" tab.

[image]

Comment: Saved my day, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem with Tamil language. one difference is I couldn't find set language option in pop-up dialogue when I right click it.

But if I select and replace the typed text with some other letter and then when we press undo. we get correct form of words and letters!!!!!!

This is the another solution. but I couldn't understand why am I not getting 'Set Language' option in the pop-up menu.

Any ways thanks for your help.

Comment: Because the solution in my answer was for *Onenote for Windows 10*, not *Onenote*. In Onenote you need to change the "proofing language". You can do this by going to the Review tab and then to the "language" tab. Then you can change the proofing language.

Comment: By the way, I don't think this should be an answer. I am not sure about this particular SE site, but in other SE sites, your answer would be flagged for removal. Such comments should be added as a comment if you have comment privileges. Also, you can ask a new question if the current ones don't solve your issue.